# Reset Cumulative Sum When Condition is met

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table like this

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Weight |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   8100 |
|  2 |   8235 |
|  3 |   7950 |
|  4 |   8175 |
|  5 |   8185 |
|  6 |   7985 |
|  7 |   8180 |
+----+--------+
```

I would like to get Cumulative Sum of Weight and reset Cumulative Sum When then Cumulative Sum is greater than or equal to 20000.

```
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+
| ID | Weight | CumWeightBySum | ResetCumWeight |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 |   8100 |           8100 |           8100 |
|  2 |   8235 |          16335 |          16335 |
|  3 |   7950 |          24285 |          24285 |
|  4 |   8175 |          32460 |           8175 |    <- Reset Cumulative Sum
|  5 |   8185 |          40645 |          16350 |
|  6 |   7985 |          48630 |          24335 |
|  7 |   8180 |          56810 |           8180 |    <- Reset Cumulative Sum
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: If `ResetCumWeight` is meant to reset every 20000 then shouldn't its column values be `8100,16335,4285,12460,645,8630,16810`?

Comment: @DaleK -- an interesting comment -- often used with something is simple and shouldn't be hard to implement -- this is clearly not simple to implement in SQL.  However, my attempt is down below :D

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with doing something like this in sql is that since sql works in sets a solution would have to be recursive.  resursive is going to be slow.  If you implemented this in a front end you can use a single loop and you don't need to recurse.  So, unless there is a trick I don't know you really want to do this in the front end.

This is close to what you want

```
SELECT s2.id, s2.weight, 
 -- total, x, z, 
   part, total,
  SUM(s2.weight) OVER (PARTITION BY s2.part ORDER BY s2.id asc) as resetw
FROM (
  SELECT id, weight, 
    total,
    COALESCE(LAG(total) OVER (ORDER BY id asc) ,0) / 20000 as part
  FROM (
    select
      id, weight,
      SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY id asc) as total
    from test
   ) s1 
 ) s2
```

Honestly this is so much easier to do in a front end that doing it in SQL seems like lost effort.

Here it the fiddle if you want to play

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1111a1/28